# Why do I get 'unknown type name DetailViewController' error, only some of the time when I compile?

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, uikit

This is something that happens some times but not all the time:

header of a class

```
#import "DetailViewController.h"

@interface MasterViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, weak) DetailViewController *detailViewController;
```

error on the property line: **unknown type name DetailViewController**

then I add this line after the import and the error vanishes.

```
@class DetailViewController;
```

This is something annoying that only happens once in a while. I have a lot of classes just like that, without the class line that work perfectly. Some require the class. Ah, and sometimes it happens on a class that was working fine for days, but from a point on, Xcode decide it doesn't know the class anymore and decides to annoy you.

why?

Comment: Are you `DetailViewController` also import MasterViewController?

Comment: Which classes are imported in `DetailViewController.h`? AFAIK the only situation in which you need `@class` is when you have a circular dependency.

Comment: @WorldOfWarcraft - yes

Comment: @11684 - why is that? and how adding a Class breaks the circular dependency?

Comment: @user2778894 I think that has been answered by Peter Foti's answer. If not, I think Peter Foti can explain it better than I can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never need to do both `@class` and import the header file, you should only do one or the other. `@class` tells the compiler that the class exists somewhere in your project. In header files you should really only ever be using `@class` to reduce circular dependencies and compile faster. Then once you've written `@class` in your header, you can import the actual `.h` file inside your implementation.

In this case it looks like you do in fact have a circular dependency which is the reason for the error.

Bottom line, in `.h` files use `@class` in `.m` import the full header.

Note: If you're subclassing X then `@class` won't work and you'll have to import the full header in your `.h`